# Lost data from double and Error: Windows has triggered a breakpoint in exe. This may be due to a corruption of the heap,

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I've been working on this code for a while and I almost got it to work but I'm running into a problem. I'm loosing data when it is sorting it. The more number I input the more numbers display a just integers. [link to the image of my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiLwF.png)

Also once the code runs I'm getting a pop up window with this message (I noticed I get this error after I added the sum function and every function after that and I did not press F12):

"Windows has triggered a breakpoint in project3.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in project3.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while 
project3.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information.
"

This is my code:
Ask the user for number after the last numbered enter they have to press zero, it display back the data, displays some statistics and sorts the data.
I'm not checking for user error

(*The terminal window closes if I don't use `system("pause")` so that is why it's there and I know I'm supposed to `'delete []arr` but it will give me breakpoint message after I put zero that is why it is comment out)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
void getdata(double *arr, double &data, int &floatpt);
void display (double *arr, int floatpt);
void computesum (double *arr, int floatpt, double sum);
void computearthmeticmean (double *arr, int floatpt, double aMean);
void computeharmonicmean (double *arr, int floatpt, double hMean);
void median(double *arr, int floatpt);
void sort (double *arr, int floatpt);
int main ()
{
    double data, sum=0, aMean=0, hMean=0;
    int count=0, floatpt;
    double *arr =new double[count]; 

    getdata (arr, data, floatpt);
    cout<<"Thank you.  The data you entered are "<<endl; 
    display(arr, floatpt);
    cout<<"The following statistics were computed "<<endl;
    computesum(arr,floatpt, sum);
    computearthmeticmean(arr, floatpt, aMean);
    median(arr, floatpt);
    computeharmonicmean (arr, floatpt, hMean);
    sort(arr, floatpt);
    cout<<"The original data set is "<<endl;
    display(arr, floatpt);
    cout<<"Thank you for using this program.  Enjoy your statistics "<<endl;

    //delete []arr;


   system ("pause");
   return 0;
}
void getdata(double *arr, double &data, int &floatpt)
{
    int count=0; 

    cout<<"Please enter floating point data.\n"; 
    cout<<"After the last number has been entered press 0 (zero) \n"; 
    do
    {
        cin>>arr[count]; 
        data = arr[count]; 

        count++; 

    }while(data != 0);
    floatpt=(count-1);

 }
void display (double *arr, int floatpt)
{
    for(int i=0; i<floatpt; i++) 
    { 
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
    }

}
void computesum (double *arr, int floatpt, double sum)
{
    for (int j=0; j<floatpt; j++)
    {
        sum+=arr[j];
    }
    cout<<"Sum: "<<sum<<endl;

}
void computearthmeticmean (double *arr, int floatpt, double aMean)
{
    for (int a=0; a<floatpt; a++)
    {
        aMean+=arr[a];
    }
    aMean=aMean/floatpt;
    cout<<"Arithmetic Mean: "<<aMean<<endl;

}
void computeharmonicmean (double *arr, int floatpt, double hMean)
{
    for (int h=0; h<floatpt; h++)
    {
        hMean+=(1/arr[h]);
    }
    hMean=floatpt/hMean;
    cout<<"Harmonic Mean: "<<hMean<<endl;

}
void median(double *arr, int floatpt)
{
    int temp;
    double median;

    for (int s=0; s<floatpt; s++) 
    {
        for (int r=0; r<(floatpt-1); ++r) 
        {
            if (arr[r] > arr[r+1]) 
            {
                temp = arr[r];
                arr[r] = arr[r+1];
                arr[r+1] = temp;
            }
        }

        if (floatpt%2 == 0)
        {
            median = (arr[s/2] + arr[(s/2)-1])/2.0;
        }
        else
        {
            median = arr[s/2]/1.0;
        }
    }

    cout<<"Median: "<<median<<endl;

}
void sort (double *arr, int floatpt)
{
    cout<<"The sorted data set is: "<<endl;
    for (int sd=0; sd<floatpt; sd++) 
    {
        cout<<arr[sd]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int count=0, floatpt;
double *arr =new double[count];
```

`count` is 0, so the array you create has no allocation. In `getdata` you therefore read into memory locations that are out of bounds.:

Did you intend to reallocate later?

Perhaps if you tried to use a `std::vector<double>`, then things would work out. It automatically resizes itself, and it's easy to do bounds checking.

Something like this (not tested):

```
#include <vector>
// ...
std::vector<double> data;
getdata(arr);
// ...

void getdata(std::vector<double>& arr)
{
    double nextValue;

    cout<<"Please enter floating point data.\n"; 
    cout<<"After the last number has been entered press 0 (zero) \n"; 
    cin>>nextValue; 
    while(nextValue != 0)
    {
       arr.push_back(nextValue);
       cin >> nextValue;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you i got it the only change I made was I changed `std::vector<double> data` to `std::vector<double> arr`. If it not to much to ask can you show me how it would be done with the sum and I could figure out the rest. In class we've only looked at one example using the vector library.

Comment: You could employ the use of [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) to perform summation on `arr`. `double sum = std::accumulate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 0);`